# Template pattern for breaking down larger classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am implementing a API sdk that has a huge number of operations and want to split it into more manageable classes by grouping certain operations.

Taking one of Spring-socials examples for Twitter they have broken each "group" of operations into specific classes and then initialised them all from a a wrapper class:. They call this using the "Template" pattern. But this is not how I understand the the Template pattern.

Is this indeed the Template pattern? And are there any better alternatives to breaking down a large class of operations like this?

I can not use a CRUD style as the operations are not as simple as that.

```
    public class TwitterTemplate extends AbstractOAuth1ApiBinding implements Twitter {

            private TimelineOperations timelineOperations;

            private UserOperations userOperations;

            private FriendOperations friendOperations;

            private ListOperations listOperations;

            private SearchOperations searchOperations;

            private DirectMessageOperations directMessageOperations;

            private BlockOperations blockOperations;

    public TwitterTemplate(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret) {
            super(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
            initSubApis();
        }
private void initSubApis() {
        this.userOperations = new UserTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(), isAuthorizedForApp());
        this.directMessageOperations = new DirectMessageTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(), isAuthorizedForApp());
        this.friendOperations = new FriendTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(), isAuthorizedForApp());
        this.listOperations = new ListTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(), isAuthorizedForApp());
        this.timelineOperations = new TimelineTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(), isAuthorizedForApp());
        this.searchOperations = new SearchTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(), isAuthorizedForApp());
        this.blockOperations = new BlockTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(),isAuthorizedForApp());
        this.geoOperations = new GeoTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(), isAuthorizedForApp());
        this.streamOperations = new StreamingTemplate(getRestTemplate(), isAuthorized(), isAuthorizedForApp());
    }
```

Comment: To improve testability and reduce [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)), you should use an [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) framework to inject / initialize your depependencies instead of your `initSubApis()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean [Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) (which is sometimes called [Template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/307452/6-common-use-of-Template-Design-pattern-Design-pat)). This is not Template Method, because there is no template method in your class that calls the methods to be redefined in sub-classes (that I can see).

If the problem you have is too many methods for a class, then you need to apply some basic class design: [refactorings, such as "extract class",](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) that aim for [high cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29#High_cohesion), the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [GRASP High Cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#High_Cohesion):

> *High cohesion means that the responsibilities of a given element are strongly related and highly focused. Breaking programs into classes and subsystems is an example of activities that increase the cohesive properties of a system.*